# Extract Month From Date Field

Tags: postgresql, extract

I have a date field in a postgresql database (field name is input) how can I extract the month only from the date field?  I used the syntax below, but I want it to show the actual month name, not a numeric value for the month

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM input) AS "Month"
```

So if the date in the field input was 04/26/2016 this syntax returns 4, how could I alter this to return April

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may find this useful

`SELECT to_char(to_timestamp (date_part('month', timestamp '2016-04-26 20:38:40')::text, 'MM'), 'Month')`

All the best

Ref [Postgresql (Current) Section 9.9. Date/Time Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 22):

A simpler version.

`to_char(input, 'Month') AS Month`

Source : [Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: Yeah definitely recommend this answer over the accepted one and avoid the casting.

Answer (score -1):

```
select date_trunc('month', input)::date as Monat
```

Ref https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html
date_trunc ( text, timestamp ) → timestamp

Truncate to specified precision; see Section 9.9.2

```
date_trunc('hour', timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40') → 2001-02-16 20:00:00
```

Comment: It does not give the requested result, namely a month name.