# SQL: average by month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to calculate the monthly average per venue for a variable which has daily data. My date variable has a numeric format "YYYYMMDD". 
My data looks like this:

```
date        venue   metric
20150203    1       0.78
20150204    1       0.65
20150205    1       0.90
20150206    1       0.40
20150203    2       0.74
20150204    2       0.77
20150205    2       0.88
20150206    2       0.64
20150203    3       0.78
20150204    3       0.92
20150205    3       0.94
20150206    3       0.60
```

Comment: which database type?

Comment: cast your date from numeric to varchar(8)... date functions should be able identify year month well in my case... otherwise apply culture/region

Comment: Store dates as the appropriate `date` type, not numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing dates as *dates* not as *numbers*, regardless of the database.  In any case, something like the following should work in any database:

```
select floor(date / 100) as yyyymm, venue, avg(metric)
from t
group by floor(date / 100), venue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT
    month,
    venue,
    AVG(metric)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(CAST(your_date_field AS TEXT), 'YYYYMMDD')) AS month, venue, metric
    FROM 
        your_table
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY
    month, venue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DATE, 5,2) AS MONTH, VENUE, AVG (METRIC)
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(DATE, 5,2), VENUE
```

Also, I agree with everyone here on you should store dates as a date value.

Comment: yeah sorry it is saved as date. Im quite new to SQL. Anyway, I tried "select year(date), month(date), metric ......" but got an error : "ERROR:  function year(date) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT year(date) as year, month(date) as month, market_id, ...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********"

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869703/extract-month-from-date-field, and see if that helps you extract the month from your date field.